# google maps not displaying using ionic/angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic2 for showing google maps. But I am getting blank page when i run the below following code.

```
export class NearByStoresPage {

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private confData: ConferenceData) {
    this.loadNearByOffers();
  }

  loadNearByOffers(){

    let options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

        (position) => {
            let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);               

            let mapOptions = {
                center: latLng,
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              position: map.getCenter()
            });

            let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";          

            let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: content
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        },

        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }, options

    );
  }
}
```

And i include the  file in the index.html file,

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>
```

Html file,

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>Near By Offers</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="map-page">
  <div id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

But the following code is working fine,

```
this.confData.getMap().then(mapData => {
      let mapEle = document.getElementById('map');

      let map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
        center: mapData.find(d => d.center),
        zoom: 16
      });

      mapData.forEach(markerData => {
        let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: `<h5>${markerData.name}</h5>`
        });

        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: markerData,
          map: map,
          title: markerData.name
        });

        marker.addListener('click', () => {
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      });

      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', () => {
        mapEle.classList.add('show-map');
      });

    });
```

Comment: I have same problem , any one have solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Add width and height to your map DIV:

```
<div id="map" style="width:800px;height:600px"></div>
```

Also this line

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>
```

needs to specify callback function

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is because you're calling the `this.loadNearByOffers();` method in the constructor. That method, tries then to load the map by getting an element from the DOM

`document.getElementById("map")`

But when your constructor is executed, that element in the DOM does not exist yet, and that's why the map is not loaded properly.

I don't know which version of Ionic are you using in the project, but you can use one of the [page events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/) like `ionViewDidEnter` to be sure that the code will be executed (and the map will be initialized) after the DOM elements are available.

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  // the html of the page is now available
  this.loadNearByOffers();
}
```

You can find a working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zhdu1K?p=preview).

Comment: in my case I am calling the getElementById inside the ionViewLoaded method, still the map does not show up.Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.36
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.19
OS:
Node Version: v4.4.7

Comment: A few questions: Are the height and width of the map element set to 100% (or any other size)? Are you using a valid API KEY when importing the js from Google? Is that happening only on the device or in the browser too?

Comment: Yes the width and height is set to 100%, I am not using an API Key, Yes I am importing the JS from google, happening on device, ionic view and browser with ionic serve

Comment: Hmmm could you please use that plunker to include your code? maybe if you can replicate the issue there I could take a look at it

Comment: Find link to the plunk to the important files https://plnkr.co/edit/v3pzQ9iZHq1o0GXIbYTk?p=catalogue

Comment: I'm getting a lot of javascript errors in that plunker, currently it can't be executed...

Comment: Find a complete workspace on cloud 9 IDE for the project here https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/tag cd into the tagon folder and run ionic serve

Answer (score 1):

Try calling method loadNearByOffers() as follows.

```
ionViewLoaded(){
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.loadNearByOffers();
   }
}
```

the map should get loaded on device ready event.